# why does return statement not break recursive for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, recursion, return, sudoku

Please i am trying to build a Sudoku solver in JavaScript but i face a problem when i get to the **solve function**, the recursive loop doesn't stop when the board is full. It executes till the end even after finding the solution. Please I'll be grateful if i can get some help. Here is what i tried doing:

```
class SudokuSolver {

  // convert puzzle string to 2D array
  boardParser(puzzleString) {
    var board = [];
    var i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 81; i += 9) {
      var boardRow = [];
      for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        boardRow.push(puzzleString.charAt(i + j));
      }
      board.push(boardRow)
    }

    // console.log(board);
    return board;
  }

  // Look for empty space on board (empty space = ".")
  // return [row, col] if empty space found
  // return [-1,-1] if no empty space found (board is full)
  getDot(board) {
    var i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        if (board[i][j] == ".") {
          return [i, j];
        }
      }
    }
    return [-1, -1];
  }

  checkRowPlacement(board, row, column, value) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      if (board[row][i] == value) {
        // console.log("row check false");
        return {
          valid: false
        };
      }
    }
    // console.log("row check true");
    return {
      valid: true
    }
  }

  checkColPlacement(board, row, column, value) {
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      if (board[i][column] == value) {
        // console.log("col check false")
        return {
          valid: false
        }
      }
    }
    // console.log("col check true")
    return {
      valid: true
    };
  }

  checkRegionPlacement(board, row, column, value) {
    var i, j;
    var regRow = Math.floor(row / 3) * 3;
    var regCol = Math.floor(column / 3) * 3;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (board[regRow + i][regCol + j] == value) {
          // console.log("reg check false")
          return {
            valid: false
          }
        }
      }
    }
    // console.log("reg check true");
    return {
      valid: true
    }
  }

  checkvalue(board, row, column, value) {
    var rowCheck = this.checkRowPlacement(board, row, column, value).valid
    var colCheck = this.checkColPlacement(board, row, column, value).valid
    var regCheck = this.checkRegionPlacement(board, row, column, value).valid
    // console.log(rowCheck, colCheck, regCheck);

    if (rowCheck && colCheck && regCheck) {
      // console.log(true)
      return true;
    }
    // console.log(false)
    return false;
  }

  // convert 2D array back to string
  stringifyBoard(board) {
    var string = ""
    var i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        string += board[i][j];
      }
    }

    // console.log(string);
    return string;
  }

  // check for any more empty spaces
  solved(board) {
    var i, j;

    if (this.getDot(board)[0] == -1) {
      return true
    }
    return false
  }

  solve(puzzleString) {
    var board = this.boardParser(puzzleString)
    var emptySpot = this.getDot(board);
    var row = emptySpot[0];
    var column = emptySpot[1];

    // full board condition
    if (this.solved(board)) {
      return puzzleString;
    }

    for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
      if (this.checkvalue(board, row, column, i)) {
        board[row][column] = i;
        var boardString = this.stringifyBoard(board);
        this.solve(boardString);
      }
    }

    // if board is unsolvable return false
    return false;
  }
}

const input = '5..91372.3...8.5.9.9.25..8.68.47.23...95..46.7.4.....5.2.......4..8916..85.72...3';

console.log(new SudokuSolver().solve(input));
```

it returns false, but the puzzle string is valid and also when i console log in the **full board condition** it shows the solved string but doesn't return it.

Comment: There's a lot here to review. Can you boil it down a bit? Remember, `return` only exits the current function, not all functions.

Comment: Is this your code? Did you author it I mean? And if so where are your debugging details? Because it has smell of copied code.

Comment: Can you give an input for which the issue is reproducible? The input you have given returns the result as false.

Comment: Hello @tadman, thank you for your kind respond. I was hoping the `return` will break the `recursive loop`  when it doesn't find any more empty spaces. Please if am wrong about the return in that context help me out I'll be grateful.

Comment: Hello @GetSet, i got inspired by this article `https://medium.com/swlh/backtracking-algorithm-to-solve-sudoku-puzzle-in-javascript-732aedcf5e2` and tried to use it for my project. I didn't copy and paste code snippets as it wouldn't be very helpful to my learning journey.

Comment: Hello @maddy, please if you add a `console.log(puzzleString)` in the `full board condition` located in the `solve function`, you'll get the desired output but it doesn't break and return the result rather it executes the `for loop` till the end and returns a `false` which is the return for `no solution found`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So once the board is solved and if this.solved(board) returns true, you are returning the solved board. But this is only at the last level of recursion chain. You need to check at every level of recursion if this particular move reaches a solved board state. Hence, validate the result of the next level and if it returns a solved board, return the solved board from the current level too. I have made appropriate changes in the solve function-

```
solve(puzzleString) {
    var board = this.boardParser(puzzleString)
    var emptySpot = this.getDot(board);
    var row = emptySpot[0];
    var column = emptySpot[1];

    // full board condition
    if (this.solved(board)) {
      return puzzleString;
    }

    for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
      if (this.checkvalue(board, row, column, i)) {
        board[row][column] = i;
        var boardString = this.stringifyBoard(board);
        var result = this.solve(boardString);
        if(result !== false){
            return result;
        }
      }
    }

    // if board is unsolvable return false
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @maddy, this worked perfectly. Thanks so much i learnt much from your explanation.

Comment: @FruPromise Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
   if (this.checkvalue(board, row, column, i)) {
     board[row][column] = i;
     var boardString = this.stringifyBoard(board);
     
     if(this.solve(boardString)) return true; //I've a modification here
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hello @Harney, thank you for your respond but please it didn't work. I wish to get the return from the `full board condition` rather than the `false` which returns at the bottom of the function meaning `no solution found`.

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write any code to stop the function when the solution is found.
Here is my solution:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
  if (this.checkvalue(board, row, column, i)) {
    board[row][column] = i;
    var boardString = this.stringifyBoard(board);
    var sol = this.solve(boardString); // change
    if (sol) return sol // change
  }
}
```

I have done a similar one in python a while ago.
Check it here if you are interested: https://onlinegdb.com/SJt2PQrjP

Comment: Hello @Poorna Chandra R, thank you for your response, but this didn't work

Comment: @Fru Promise, It is working for me. Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lyxvenu5/  Just remove the line     `this.solve(boardString);` and add     `var sol = this.solve(boardString);    if (sol) return sol;`